# How do I check if the move is valid or not made by Knight and Bishop

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, chess

Complete the following function to validate the move of a given chess piece and return True (boolean) if the move is valid or False(boolean) if the move is invalid. The chessboard is given below for your reference.

Function takes 3 arguments

**piece** can be a **"Knight"** or **"Bishop"**

**currentpos**(a string) is a combination of row and column it be anything between "a1" to "h8". currentpos represents the cell on the chessboard where the piece is currently located

**nextpos**(a string) is also a combination of row and column and can also be between from "a1" to "h8". nextpos represents the cell to which the piece is intended to be moved

[image]

I have a hard time understanding this question. Can anyone tell me the correct approach for this problem?

```
def valid_move_or_not(piece,currentpos,nextpos):
    #Write your code here
    return True

if __name__=='__main__':
    #you can run your tests here
    print(valid_move_or_not("Knight","a1","a2"))
```

Comment: Here is an auxiliary question: can the knight move from `a1` to `a2`? (and why).

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the displacement in the X and Y axes. You'll find the pattern.

- Valid Bishop move results in equal displacement in both axes.
- Valid Knight move results in 1,2 or 2,1 blocks displacement in X, Y axes respectively.

```py
def valid_move_or_not(piece, currentpos, nextpos):
    coord = lambda x: (ord(x[0]) - ord('a'), int(x[1]))
    xdiff = abs(coord(currentpos)[0] - coord(nextpos)[0])
    ydiff = abs(coord(currentpos)[1] - coord(nextpos)[1])
    if piece == "Bishop":
        return xdiff == ydiff
    elif piece == "Knight":
        return xdiff == 2 and ydiff == 1 or xdiff == 1 and ydiff == 2
```

Answer (score 0):

It asks you to code the move rule of chess pieces. You can google if you are not familiar with chess.

As a simple example, you can check the validity of a Rook move like below

```
def valid_move_or_not(piece,currentpos,nextpos):
    if currentpos == nextpos:
        return False
    if piece == 'Rook':
        return (currentpos[0] == nextpos[0]) or (currentpos[1] == nextpos[1])
```

Comment: I still couldn't figure logic for knight and bishop. Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @Lucas, perhaps starting with Bishop is simpler. Bishop moves diagonally, which changes both coordinates by the same amount (in abs value)

Comment: This is too simple, what if there are pieces between start and end square?